# AngularJs - "deferred" or "batched" directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know the first thing you might say is "what have you tried", but the only answer I can give is "google" or "books". So unfortunately there is no code here.

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1 - Create a directive that takes 2 paramaters like so

```
<resource resource-area="AREA" resource-key="KEY" />
```

2 - During compile, instead of changing the output straightaway, put the requested "resource" directives (or their related objects, eg element, attrs) into a tempory "batch" in the $scope.

3 - Once compile has completed (or nearly completed??) for the view that the directives are in, then all the directives are finally compiled

The purpose of this is so that only a single ajax call is made for all of the directives, instead of one per-directive.

I hope this makes sense. Honestly, I've trawled through the documentation and search engines as best I can and can't find an answer. There may not be one of course. But I'm hopeful :)

Comment: you can have all the `resource` directives [requiring](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) a single directive with a sole purpose: to load the aggregated resources.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT: Slightly different solution after creating proof-of-concept code below.***

What if you would change your solution to use <s>an http interceptor and</s> a service instead?

1. Directives get compiled and linked
2. They fire up http requests usings promises for the results
3. The http requests get <s>intercepted and</s> stored in a service
4. <s>When all directives are done with their work, you can tell the service the fire up your batch request</s> The service fires up the requests at a pre-determined interval of time.

---

The new solution does not involve using an http interceptor, because there were problems with circular dependencies while testing the concept.

You can see it working at http://plnkr.co/edit/eCb3wm

First, create a service to save all requests and fire them at a later point in time:

```
app.service('HttpBatch', function($q, $http, $interval) {
  var batch = [];

  // Fires whatever is inside the batch
  // Removes from the batch after firing
  var fireBatch = function() {
    while (batch.length > 0) {
      var batchObj = batch.shift();
      console.log('Firing batchObj: ', batchObj.config);
      // Fire the request and resolve its promise
      // with whatever the http promise resolves to
      batchObj.deferred.resolve($http(batchObj.config));
    }
  };

  // Adds a request object to the list
  // Returns a promise for the request passed
  var addRequest = function(reqConfig) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    batch.push({
      config: reqConfig,
      deferred: deferred
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  // Fires every 3s
  // Feel free to change the interval to what makes most sense for you
  $interval(fireBatch, 3000);

  return addRequest;
});
```

Then, use it in your directives instead of $http.
To show how it can be used, here is a sample directive that uses the batch service to make its requests.

```
app.directive('fireReq', function(HttpBatch) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      var me = 'Directive ' + attrs['fireReq'];
      console.log(me);
      // Example url only
      // Pass a config object just as when using $http
      // Returns a promise
      HttpBatch({
        method:'GET',
        url:'http://run.plnkr.co/user/' + attrs['fireReq']
      }).then(function onSuccess (res) {
        console.log(me + ' got success response: ', res);
      }, function onFailure (res) {
        console.log(me + ' got failure response: ', res);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The whole solution makes extensive use of $q and promises, so you should be aware of them before you try to understand how the above code works.

Also, be aware that you should add some tests to the code before using it in production.

I hope that helps you in your particular case. It was a nice idea to learn for me though :)

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. I know how to intercept http requests, but "when all directives are done.." - how would I watch for that?

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 I modified slightly the idea and made a proof-of-concept code, please take a look.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to look into this. I hope, as you say, you did enjoy it! I will have a look and try to implement as soon as I get a chance. Then will feedback.. :)